# Not able to add Hangout button using APIs in my page

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-hangouts

All I am trying is to add a basic Hangout button component which will initiate Google's Hangout. I am following steps mentioned in [Google Developer](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button#examples) , but after all the efforts, I am struggling to get around with the following issue:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').(anonymous function) @ core:rpc:shindig.random:shindig.sha1.js?c=2:838
3cb=gapi.loaded_0:112 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').(anonymous function) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:112
```

Here is the snippet which i am using to develop hangout button in page:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
    <div id="placeholder-div"></div>
    <script>
    window.____gcfg = {
      lang: 'en-US',
      parsetags: 'onload'
    };
      gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div', {
          'render': 'createhangout',
          'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : '902502537504'}],
          'widget_size': 175
        });
    </script>
```

I have also enabled my google+ hangout service using https://console.developers.google.com/project/grabhouseportal/apiui/apiview/plusHangouts/overview

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Note `file://`. Don't open the html file with the browser directly. You need to run a local web server and navigate to localhost to render the html page.